# Mariadb runs code that is inside comments

Tags: python, mariadb

My mariadb install,(Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.8-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1), in Arch Linux, is reading the code inside comments.

I have a personal note-taking app, written in Python that, to update fields in the database, has this code:

```
import time
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
import click


def update():
    coluna = input(click.style(' Column? » ', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    ident = input(click.style(' ID? » ', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    print(click.style(' Write your update', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    update = click.edit()
    vari = [coluna, update, ident]

    try:
        conn = connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="mic",
                password="xxxx",
                database="notes")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = """ UPDATE notes SET %s = %s WHERE id = %s) """
        cur.execute(query, vari)
        conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print("Error while connecting to db", e)
    finally:
        if(conn):
            conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update()
```

If, for example, I try to update the note content with the note below (this a real note I tried to upload):

```
/* Example:                                                     */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE BookSearch USING fts5(ID, Title, Desc); */
/* INSERT INTO BookSearch SELECT ID, Title, Desc FROM Book;     */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* Searches are done like this:                                 */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* SELECT Title FROM BookSearch WHERE BookSearch MATCH 'cat'    */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
```

I get this error message:

```
Error while connecting to db 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cat'    */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */...' at line 1
```

As you can see, the code is all commented out.

But what I find stranger, is the fact that if I put this content into my add-a-note code, it passes with no problems. In fact I can put it without comments and there is no error messages.

This is the code that adds a note:

```
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
import time
import click
import fire


def add():
    titulo = input(click.style(' Title? » ', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    kwd1 = input(click.style(' Choose a keyword » ', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    kwd2 = input(click.style(' Choose another ... » ', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    kwd3 = input(click.style(' And another... » ', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    print(click.style(' Write the note.', fg='magenta', bold=True))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    nota = click.edit().rstrip()
    answers = [titulo, kwd1, kwd2, kwd3, nota]
    # Na apresentação da db, havia uma linha vazia entre os campos note e time. rstrip elimina essa linha.
    try:
        conn = connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="mic",
                password="xxxx",
                database="notes")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = """ INSERT INTO notes (title, k1, k2, k3, note) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """
        cur.execute(query, answers)
        conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print("Error while connecting to db", e)
    finally:
        if(conn):
            conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(add)
```

I've googled the problem for some time, but this is not, it appears, a common problem. As there is so little information about it.
This app had an original version where the db used was SQLite3, and I never had this problems with it. Which is funny, considering that most of my notes on databases, refer to SQLite's code syntax.

What I would like was some insight on what might be causing this, since I have no idea.

Thanks for all the help

EDIT:
@Luuk asked me for logs of this type of event, so here it is an example.

Before that I should warn you that I was wrong answering a commentary. The problem does not appear if I use the cli app. It manifests only through the python connection.

```
*************************** 24. row ***************************
  event_time: 2021-01-24 17:02:28.643027
   user_host: [mic] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
   thread_id: 7
   server_id: 1
command_type: Connect
    argument: mic@localhost on notes using TCP/IP
*************************** 25. row ***************************
  event_time: 2021-01-24 17:02:28.643267
   user_host: mic[mic] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
   thread_id: 7
   server_id: 1
command_type: Query
    argument: SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
*************************** 26. row ***************************
  event_time: 2021-01-24 17:02:28.643436
   user_host: mic[mic] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
   thread_id: 7
   server_id: 1
command_type: Query
    argument: SET @@session.autocommit = OFF
*************************** 27. row ***************************
  event_time: 2021-01-24 17:02:28.643883
   user_host: mic[mic] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
   thread_id: 7
   server_id: 1
command_type: Query
    argument: UPDATE notes SET 'note' = 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
right syntax to use near \'data in the example is oriented
vertically it could be presented in one line....\' at line 1\nMariaDB [notes]>
update notes\n    -> set note = \' The data in the example is oriented vertically
\n    \'> it could be presented in one line. I just think that\n    \'> this way
is clearer.\n    \'> Notice the command after each entry.
They\'re necessary,\n    -> Don\'t use the word \'time\' for the timestamp,
 it\'s a\n    -> reserved word.    -> An example of a successful completion:
\n    -> -------------------------------------------------------\n    -> 
CREATE TABLE bkmks( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,\n    ->
title VARCHAR(100),\n
    -> comment TEXT,\n
    -> link VARCHAR(200),\n
    -> k1 VARCHAR(100),\n
    -> k2 VARCHAR(100),\n
    -> k3 VARCHAR(100),\n
    -> tempo DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);' WHERE id = '57')
*************************** 28. row ***************************
  event_time: 2021-01-24 17:02:28.644037
   user_host: mic[mic] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
   thread_id: 7
   server_id: 1
command_type: Quit
    argument: 
*************************** 29. row ***************************
```

Comment: Yes I can. I have the same result, same error message.

Comment: Can you enable [general_log and general_log_file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html), and show the statements that are received by the database ?

Comment: Hi @Luuk, please the edit I did to the post. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I looked at the log, and it seems something is missing (I think there should be single quotes around the `%s`, like `'%s'`)  but my python skills are too low to get a simple example running...

Comment: No, that's not it. I tried it and nothing changed. I think they would be redundant, given that we already have a multi-line comment symbol in there. But, again, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I can;'t reproduce the exact same error, but I suspect the problem is that you are passing the column name to `cursor.execute` as a value.  This results in the column name being quoted in the query, which is not what you want

```sql
UPDATE notes SET 'note' = 'spam' WHERE id = 42
```

You need to set the column name using string formatting before executing the query:

```py
    vari = [update, ident]
    ...
    query = f""" UPDATE notes SET `{coluna}` = %s WHERE id = %s) """
    cur.execute(query, vari)
```

If the input is not trusted you should ensure that the value of `coluna` matches an actual column name in the table to prevent SQL injection.